# Eclipse PyDev Autocomplete Issues

Tags: eclipse, autocomplete, pydev, errno

I installed PyDev in Eclipse on my Mac. Whenever I am writing code, it has only a few suggestions and is seemingly incomplete. For example, whenever I type 'r', it only suggests "raise()" and "return()". However, all of the other functions that I would expect for it to suggest still execute at runtime.

This is the error:

Error connecting to python process.
 - the process in NOT ALIVE anymore (output=0) - 
ProcessInfo:

- Executed: /usr/bin/python -u 
  /Users//Downloads/eclipse 
  2/plugins/org.python.pydev_2.6.0.2012062818
  /pysrc/pycompletionserver.py 52958 52957
- Environment:
  APP_ICON_2099=../Resources/Eclipse.icns
  Apple_PubSub_Socket_Render=/tmp/launch-
  4HHiSZ/Render
  COMMAND_MODE=unix2003
  DISPLAY=/tmp/launch-hu6CLm/org.x:0
  HOME=/Users/
  JAVA_STARTED_ON_FIRST_THREAD_2099=1
  LOGNAME=
  PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
  PYTHONPATH=/Users//Downloads/ecli
  pse 2/plugins/org.python.pydev_2.6.0.2012062818
  /pysrc/pydev_sitecustomize:
  /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.
  framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python26.zip:
  /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.
  framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6:
  /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.
  framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/plat-darwin:
  /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.
  framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/plat-mac:
  /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.
  framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/plat-mac/lib-
  scriptpackages:/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.
  framework/Versions/2.6/Extras/lib/python:
  /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.
  framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/lib-tk:
  /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.
  framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/lib-old:
  /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.
  framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload:
  /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.
  framework/Versions/2.6/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC:
  /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.
  framework/Versions/2.6/Extras/lib/python/wx-2.8-
  mac-unicode
  SHELL=/bin/bash
  SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/launch-phfnZP/Listeners
  TMPDIR=/var/folders/Kr/Krv2afoAFMa79AvxnI73IE++
  +TI/-Tmp-/
  USER=
  __CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING=0x1F5:0:0
  com.apple.java.jvmTask=JNI
- Working Dir:
  /Users//Downloads/eclipse 
  2/plugins/org.python.pydev_2.6.0.2012062818/pysrc
- OS:
  Mac OS X
- Std output:
  pycompletionserver will start
  pycompletionserver creating socket
  pycompletionserver received error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users//Downloads/eclipse 
  2/plugins/org.python.pydev_2.6.0.2012062818
  /pysrc/pycompletionserver.py", line 261, in run
  s.bind((HOST, self.thisPort))
  File "", line 1, in bind
  gaierror: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, 
  or not known
- Err output:
  Error connecting with parameters: host: localhost 
  port: 52957
  Exception in thread Thread-1:
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.
  framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/threading.py", 
  line 522, in __bootstrap_inner
  self.run()
  File "/Users//Downloads/eclipse 
  2/plugins/org.python.pydev_2.6.0.2012062818
  /pysrc/pycompletionserver.py", line 261, in run
  s.bind((HOST, self.thisPort))
  File "", line 1, in bind
  gaierror: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, 
  or not known

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i solved my Problem (was nearly the same):

i had

127.0.0.1 localhost

::1 localhost

written in my "hosts"-file:

HOW TO SOLVE:

1. open Terminal
2. sudo nano /etc/hosts
3. enter password
4. find both entries and comment them out with a "#" for example:

   `#127.0.0.1 localhost
   #::1 localhost`
5. CTRL+X
6. Y (on european Keyboard Z=Y)
7. ENTER

=> Solved

Answer (score 0):

It seems that for some reason it's not being able to connect to 'localhost', this usually means some problem in your machine configuration.

Take a look at:

https://superuser.com/questions/207244/os-x-cant-resolve-localhost-suddenly

https://superuser.com/questions/142736/cant-resolve-localhost-on-mac-os-x-server

to see if that's your case... you can also try to edit:

/Users/tywhitehouse10/Downloads/eclipse 2/plugins/org.python.pydev_2.6.0.2012062818/pysrc/pydev_localhost.py

and make the function 'get_localhost' return '127.0.0.1' directly (but this is not a real solution, just a way to check if binding to the address directly instead of localhost works, as your localhost should definitely resolve properly).