# Eclipse Oxygen freezes when writing with PyDev

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

I am trying to create a project using PyDev in Eclipse Oxygen, and whenever I start typing, Eclipse stops responding. It doesn't seem to be because of the completion, it works fine in Java projects and it's able to suggest `import` and other keywords. I'm typing a for loop when it freezes, I get about half way through the `range` keyword usually. I've restarted Eclipse several times and tried Java without issues. I'm running Java 1.8.0_144, Python version 3.6.2, and Eclipse version 4.7.0.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

In the log file, this is the most recent error:

`java.lang.RuntimeException: Attempt: 4 of 5 failed, trying again...(socket connected: still null) at org.python.pydev.core.log.Log.log(Log.java:54) at org.python.pydev.editor.codecompletion.shell.AbstractShell.startIt(AbstractShell.java:353) at org.python.pydev.editor.codecompletion.shell.ShellsContainer.getServerShell(ShellsContainer.java:232) at org.python.pydev.editor.codecompletion.shell.ShellsContainer.getServerShell(ShellsContainer.java:165) at org.python.pydev.editor.codecompletion.shell.AbstractShell.getServerShell(AbstractShell.java:222) at org.python.pydev.editor.codecompletion.revisited.modules.CompiledModule.createTokensFromServer(CompiledModule.java:372) at org.python.pydev.editor.codecompletion.revisited.modules.CompiledModule.<init>(CompiledModule.java:176) at org.python.pydev.editor.codecompletion.revisited.SystemModulesManager.getBuiltinModule(SystemModulesManager.java:332)
at org.python.pydev.editor.codecompletion.revisited.SystemModulesManager.getModule(SystemModulesManager.java:371)
    at com.python.pydev.analysis.additionalinfo.AbstractAdditionalDependencyInfo.updateKeysIfNeededAndSave(AbstractAdditionalDependencyInfo.java:256)
    at com.python.pydev.analysis.system_info_builder.InterpreterInfoBuilder.syncInfoToPythonPath(InterpreterInfoBuilder.java:160)
    at com.python.pydev.analysis.system_info_builder.InterpreterInfoBuilder.syncInfoToPythonPath(InterpreterInfoBuilder.java:86)
    at org.python.pydev.editor.codecompletion.revisited.SynchSystemModulesManager.synchronizeManagerToNameToInfoPythonpath(SynchSystemModulesManager.java:390)
    at org.python.pydev.editor.codecompletion.revisited.SyncSystemModulesManagerScheduler$SynchJob.run(SyncSystemModulesManagerScheduler.java:261)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:56)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Eclipse Pydev autocomplete not working with error: java.lang.RuntimeException: The python client still hasn't connected back to the eclipse java vm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23789555/eclipse-pydev-autocomplete-not-working-with-error-java-lang-runtimeexception-t)

Answer (score 1):

Check the faq on that: http://www.pydev.org/faq.html#HowToFixCodeCompletion

As a note, the problem is that PyDev is not being able to connect to a shell for getting code-completion info. The usual culprit is some firewall blocking or a misconfigured localhost -- you may want to try to return `127.0.0.1` in the `get_localhost()` method in `plugins\org.python.pydev\pysrc\_pydev_bundle\pydev_localhost.py` or maybe `::1` if using ipv6 (if that fixes it for you or if you find a different solution, please let me know -- from time to time I see some different issue and I want to keep the faq updated regarding things still not explained there or update the code to workaround different issues).

Answer (score 0):

You should check whether local socket connections are allowed in your firewall settings. You might even try to switch off the firewall to test if freezing still occurs. If not (or if you are on a machine with inet connection) you may allow local socket connections like this (and/or ipv6 equivalent):

```
iptables -I INPUT 1 -p all -s 127.0.0.1 -d 127.0.0.1 -j ACCEPT
```

Be aware that this allows all localhost communication attempts, if unsure check back with your administrator. If this solves your problem and there arise no other security issues, persist the changes with (OS dependent - on a Windows / OS-X System you want to use the appropriate administrative GUI)

```
/etc/init.d/iptables save
```